# How to show connected table data in blade view using join query in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-blade

I have two tables employess (id, pin, name, designation_code, blood_grp_code, email, phone, image) and blood_groups (id, blood_grp_code, blood_grp_name, blood_grp_sh_name).

Sample Values:

```
employees (1, 252,Mr. John, 101, 101, sample@gmail.com, +9901746207308, 101.jpg)
and blood_groups (1, 101, A+(ve),A+(ve))
```

**
Controller:**

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
//$information = DB::table('employees')-\>orderBy('id', 'desc')-\>paginate(15);  
//$information = DB::table('employees')-\>simplePaginate(15);
//return view('superadmin.employee.list',compact('information'));  
$query=Employee::latest();

      if ($request -> has('name_search') && !empty($request->input('name_search')))
      {
         $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input ('name_search') . '%')->get();
      }
      if ($request -> has('phone_search') && !empty($request->input('phone_search')))
      {
         //Exact Serching
         $query->where('phone', 'like',  $request->input ('phone_search') )->get();
      }
      if ($request -> has('pin_search') && !empty($request->input('pin_search')))
      {
         //Exact Serching
         $query->where('pin', 'like',  $request->input ('pin_search') )->get();
      }
      
      $information=$query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(50)->withQueryString();
     
      $affiliations = Affiliation::all();
      
      //$bloodgroups = BloodGroup::all();
    
      $bloodgroups = DB::table('employees')
            ->join('blood_groups', 'employees.blood_grp_code', '=', 'blood_groups.blood_grp_code')
            ->select('employees.*','blood_groups.blood_grp')
            ->get();      
    
      return view ('superadmin.employee.list',compact('information','affiliations','bloodgroups'));

}
```

**blade.php:**

```
<section class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
               <div class="card">
                  
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="table-responsive" style="font-size:12px;">
                        <table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-bordered border-primary table-sm" >
                           <thead>
                              <tr>
                                 <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Photo</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Emp. Sign.</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Regi. Sign.</th>
                                 <th scope="col">QR Code</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Pin</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Designation</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Affiliation</th>
                                 <th scope="col">NID</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Blood Group</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Institutional Email</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                                 <th scope="col">Action</th>
                              </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody id="myTable">
                              @if(count($information)>0) 
                              @foreach ($information as $item)
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    @if ($item->remarks=='PI') 
                                    <p style="color:red;"><b>Payment Incomplete (Pending)</b></p>
                                    @elseif ($item->remarks=='T') 
                                    <p style="color:red;"><b>Technical Issues (Pending)</b></p>
                                    @elseif ($item->remarks=='I') 
                                    <p style="color:warning;"><b>Initialized</b></p>
                                    @elseif ($item->remarks=='P') 
                                    <p style="color:blue;"><b>Printed</b></p>
                                    @elseif ($item->remarks=='D') 
                                    <p style="color:green;"><b>Delivered</b></p>
                                    @else 
                                    <p style="color:crimson;"><b>Others</b></p>
                                    @endif
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <img style="width: 50px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset('images/employee/avaters/'.$item->image) }}" />
                                 </td>
                                 
                                 <td>{{ $item->pin }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item-> }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->affiliation }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->nid }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->blood_grp_code }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
                                 <td>{{ $item->phone }}</td>
                                
                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
                              @else
                              <tr>
                                 <td colspan="14">Record not found</td>
                              </tr>
                              @endif
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                     <!-- For Pagination -->
                     <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
                           {{ $information->links() }}
                        </ul>
                     </nav>
                     <nav>
                        <p style="color:blue;">Displaying {{ $information->count() }} of {{$information->total() }} Id card(s).</p>
                     </nav>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

######################################################################################
Here, I want display the blood_grp_name in lieu of blood_grp_code in the list. How can i implement this? Any idea?

Here, I tried to display the blood_grp_name in lieu of blood_grp_code in the list. How can i implement this? Any idea?